# clamtk does not redirect stdout for its cron job

Tags: cron, logs, io-redirection, clamav

I have noticed that `clamtk` only redirects `stderr` to `/dev/null` and not `stdout`.

if I change the `cronjob` it creates to also redirect `stdout`, will that effect the log file it creates?

I want to use the `cronjob` as a template for using `clamscan` and need to be sure this will not affect the logging feature.

I would test this myself but I have no virus on hand and I am not skilled enough to risk getting one off of the internet.

below is the `cronjob` in question:

`/usr/bin/clamscan --database=/home/myhome/.clamtk/db -i -r /home/myhome --log="$HOME/.clamtk/history/$(date +\%b-\%d-\%Y).log" 2>/dev/null`

below is the `cronjob` I want to know if it will affect logging function:

`/usr/bin/clamscan --database=/home/myhome/.clamtk/db -i -r /home/myhome --log="$HOME/.clamtk/history/$(date +\%b-\%d-\%Y).log" > /dev/null 2>&1`

EDIT: had a false positive and logging was fine in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

after getting a false positive, I can say that using the second way does not cause problem for logging and logging works with both methods.